# Efficient way to apply a function to a list of lists

Tags: r, plyr

I have 80 lists for the project in question. Each list is a list of length 1000. I'd like to run a function on each one (each of the 1000), and assign the results back to the original object. The total data is over 150 gigs so I want to make sure this is most efficient before running it on the actual data. Is this trivial example the best way to do what I need?

```
# my actual function is obviously more complicated.
# But let's say the goal is to keep 2/5 items in each list
trivial <- function(foo) {
keep <- c("S1", "S2")
foo[which(keep %in% names(foo))]
}

sublist <- replicate(5, as.list(1:5), simplify=FALSE)
names(sublist) <- paste0("S", 1:5)
eachlist <- replicate(5, sublist, simplify = F)
a1 <- a2 <- a3 <- a4 <- a5 <- eachlist

# To clarify the layout
length(a1)
[1] 5
> length(a1[[1]])
[1] 5
> names(a1[[1]])
[1] "S1" "S2" "S3" "S4" "S5"
# I need to drop S3-S5 from each of 5 sublists of a1.
# Now I'd like to repeat this for all 80 lists named a[0-9].


# all the objects have a pattern sometextNUMBER. This list is 
# just the names of all the lists.
listz <-  as.list(ls(pattern="[a-z][0-9]"))
> listz
[[1]]
[1] "a1"

[[2]]
[1] "a2"

[[3]]
[1] "a3"

[[4]]
[1] "a4"

[[5]]
[1] "a5"
# I don't need anything returned, just for a1-a80 updated such that
# in each sublist, 3 of 5 items are dropped.

# This works fine, but my concern now is just scaling this up.
l_ply(listz, function(x){
     assign(as.character(x), llply(get(x), trivial), envir = .GlobalEnv)
    })
```

Comment: I bet using not plyr would be more efficient :)

Comment: The plyr package is notoriously slow. You may want to consider just using lapply instead.

Comment: exactly the motivation for my question :)

Comment: Where is your list of lists?  I expected something like `listz <- lapply(ls(pattern="[a-z][0-9]"), get)`.

Comment: Thanks Josh, I updated it with your example from below.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen: `ddply` is slow because `data.frames` are slow. The plyr package as a whole is not slow.  In this simple case, `l_ply` calls `lapply` directly.

Comment: @hadley perception adjusted. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: In general, it's much better to have a list of 80 lists than 80 separate variables each containing their own lists. @JoshuaUlrich's approach for constructing `listz` is a good way to get to that.

Comment: You may want to look into the `data.table` package. With so much data, you're going to want to avoid unnecessary copying of each object. Data.table is specifically designed to do operations without recopying entire objects, but if you want help regarding how to do this, you'll need to be more specific as to what `trivial` really does.

Comment: Data table is completely unsuitable for this task. Each list does not hold a simple data.frame. It holds a complex set of nested objects (n dimensional arrays) that cannot be coerced into tabular form. But thanks for the suggestion, I use data.table for other tasks.

Answer (score 2):

You could loop over the list of names, using `substitute()` and `eval()` to first construct and then execute the expressions you'd (not!) like to type individually at the command line:

```
objNames <- ls(pattern="[a-z][0-9]")

for(objName in objNames) {
    expr <- 
        substitute({
            OBJ <- lapply(OBJ, function(X) X[names(X) %in% c("S1", "S2")])
            }, list(OBJ = as.symbol(objName)))
    eval(expr)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use-case for `rapply`:

```
listz <- replicate(5, as.list(1:5), simplify=FALSE)
fun <- function(x) x*10
out <- rapply(listz, fun, how="replace")
```

Comment: This wont work above because `listz` is just a vector of listnames. Not an actual list itself. I'd still need to `get` the contents of each name in `listz` then recursively apply the function to its elements.

Comment: @Maiasaura: I still don't understand your example because your function doesn't operate on each terminal node of the list.  It looks like you want to apply a function to a list, not a list of lists.

Comment: The outer list is just the names of lists. I have `a1` through `a80` and so whatever I apply to each one needs to get assigned back to the original name. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Maiasaura: it makes sense, but you don't really have a list of lists.  You have a vector of object names, and each object is a list.  In that case, I'd just loop over the names and use a combination of `assign`, `get`, and `lapply`. That's basically what you did in your question, except I'd swap the `l_ply` with a for loop.

Comment: But you are right that it doesn't operate on each terminal node. outer list 1 = names of all lists. middle list = list of lists. Function needs to operate on the middle list but not go any lower. So it's like putting an `lapply` inside a `lapply`